# Can't enter < (less than) or > (greater than) in terminal

Tags: terminal

When I try to type "<" or ">", I get semicolons ";" and colons ":"  any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Note sure if this question should really been have migrated here. But this is a typical case of a vacuum that we have here. It's not really an android end-user question and on the other hand not a android programming question.

Anyway it looks like a typical codepage/localisation problem:

- **"<"** on an US layout is **";"** on an German (and maybe others) keyboard layout
- **">"** on an US layout is **":"** on an German (and maybe others) keyboard layout

**I take a wild guess and say that you develop under Microsoft Windows, where each windows can have a different keyboard layout.** You should see a symbol with the current layout right to the clock in the taskbar, where you can change this.

I hope I was able to point you into the right direction.